# Do you need to use <script> tag in HTML file when loading React via npm in vscode?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm very new at trying to use React in vscode.

My question is, if I use npm to install React in vscode, and then I have `import React from "react";` at the top of my .js file. Will that allow me to use React? Or do I still need to have a  tag in my HTML file with the applicable src attribute in each???

I'm not sure when I use one opposed to the other, or if/when I require both? Been googling for a while, and I'm pretty confused at this point. I can't seem to get it to work properly at all.

I have installed React via npm, and I can't seem to get a React component to render to the browser.

Comment: If the the import is placed in the script, and the script is linked to the body where everything in the HTML file can access the script, it's fine.

Comment: no problem! Hope your question is answered by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are very new to React and webdevelopment for that matter. To learn React, it is recommended to use [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/). It's [getting started documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started) will help you to get over these issues.

Once you set up create-react-app, the file you are looking for is `public/index.html`. You can open it in your editor and go (or copy) from there.

To answer your question litterally:

Yes, even when using npm, the javascript files need to be included into the html, using a `script` tag. Often times build tools are being used to combine javascript, so you only need to worry about including one file. But at least one needs to be included for it to execute.

Comment: I'm very new, yes! I did figure out how to create and app through create-react-app in the powershell. But I was curious to know how to load it in an existing vscode file.. Just wanted to learn how to do it another way, was all. 

And sorry, I don't I was clear enough.. I do have my .js file linked to my HTML file. What I wanted to know was, if I had the npm for React installed, did I still need to put 
`<script src="https::unpkg.come/react@18/udm/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>` inside the html still.

Comment: I added some more instructions to the answer. I hope, this helps. Do not get discouraged, the beginning is hard. Once you are set up, progress will become easier and easier. And to answer your comment: No, you do not need that.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate that! And thank you for filtering through my noob language and taking the time to understand!!!!